# Where can I find the japanese interface package for zabbix server?

Tags: interface, zabbix, language

Yesterday I installed zabbix server and agent on some of my EC2 Instance (running Ubuntu 16.04)
Now I want to add the japanese language interface for my zabbix server (because I'm working for a Japanese company and they asked me to do that)

The problem: when I search for available zabbix package on Ubuntu, I couldn't find it.
Besides, I tried to install with this command line

```
apt-get install zabbix-web-japanese
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zabbix-web-japanese
```

So I wonder if there is any ways to add japanese language interface.

@Edit: I tried to install some of the older version of japanese language packge from. I found the 3.0.4 version with rpm format. Since rpm format can't be used to install on ubuntu, I had to install alien to convert it to deb. But after executing the command to convert, i got this error

```
alien -i zabbix-web-japanese-3.0.4-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm
error: zabbix-web-japanese-3.0.4-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest)
Error executing "LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} 'zabbix-web-japanese-3.0.4-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm'":  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 489.
```

Comment: That package might only be needed for RHEL - if you try to select the Japanese locale in the frontend, does it not work?

Comment: @Richlv  Thanks Rich. Finally i found the locale and it worked. I never knew about this before.

Comment: Great, added as an answer so that this does not look like an unsolved issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package might only be needed for RHEL - selecting the Japanese locale in the frontend should work.